# How to group a list of lists using LINQ (ex: List<List<int>>)

Tags: c#, linq

I know I can easily do this with some for loops, but wanted to see if there was a way to do it with fluent LINQ. I'm trying to find out how many of each sub-list I have.

I was looking at [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but couldn't get it working with `GroupBy()`

Say I have a `List<List<int>` like this:

```
{
 {1,2}
 {2, 3, 4}
 {1,2}
 {1,3}
 {1,2}
}
```

and I want to group it by equal lists, like so

```
{
 <3, {1,2}>
 <1, {2, 3, 4>
 <1, {1,3}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to implement a `IEqualityComparer<List<T>>`, which you can then pass into `GroupBy`. For example:

```
public class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> lhs, List<T> rhs)
    {
        return lhs.SequenceEqual(rhs);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> list)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 23;
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                hash = (hash * 31) + (item == null ? 0 : item.GetHashCode());
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var counts = lists.GroupBy(x => x, 
                           (key, lists) => new { List = key, Count = lists.Count() },
                           new ListEqualityComparer<int>());
```

Comment: very nice! in the `foreach`, should it be `hash +=` ?

Comment: @mateuscb: Nope, the aim is to keep the hash codes distinct for {1, 2} and {2, 1} for example - i.e. make order matter.

Comment: that's exactly what I need. I was just about to write that I didn't understand what that code did, then I saw the addition of the (). Perfect!

Comment: @mateuscb: I only added the brackets for clarity - the semantics of the code are the same as they were before. Glad they helped though :)

Comment: I don't understand the int hash = 23 and the hash * 31. I did this with int hash = 0 and then hash = ( item == null etc...) and it worked fine.

Comment: @user890332: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment - it's not clear what your final code was. Note that it's entirely possible to have code that computes a hash code that works, but is very poor for efficiency.

Comment: I was just wondering why you need to set the hash initially to 23 and then multiply it by 31 and add it to the gethashcode.

Comment: @user890332: Just a simple way of implementing it, that's all.