# Fastest way for Linq to find duplicate Lists?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a data structure of:

```
class TheClass
{
    int NodeID;
    double Cost;
    List<int> NodeIDs;
}
```

And a List with data:

```
27 -- 10.0 -- 1, 5, 27
27 -- 10.0 -- 1, 5, 27
27 -- 10.0 -- 1, 5, 27
27 -- 15.5 -- 1, 4, 13, 14, 27
27 -- 10.0 -- 1, 4, 25, 26, 27
27 -- 15.5 -- 1, 4, 13, 14, 27
35 -- 10.0 -- 1, 4, 13, 14, 35
```

I want to reduce it to the unique NodeIDs lists

```
27 -- 10.0 -- 1, 5, 27
27 -- 15.5 -- 1, 4, 13, 14, 27
27 -- 10.0 -- 1, 4, 25, 26, 27
35 -- 10.0 -- 1, 4, 13, 14, 35
```

Then I'll be summing the Cost column (Node 27 total cost: 10.0 + 15.5 + 10.0 = 35.5) -- that part is straight forward.

What is the fastest way to remove the duplicate rows / find uniques?

Production data set will have NodeIDs lists of 100 to 200 IDs, about 1,500 in List with around 500 being unique.

I'm 100% focused on speed -- if adding some other data would help, I'm happy to (I've tried hashing the lists into a SHA value, but that turned out slower than my current grunt exhaustive search).

Comment: SHA is an expensive way to generate a unique identifier for each list.  Perhaps simply concatenating the list with a separator would be fast enough?

Comment: Did you try with a simple `.Distinct()`, possibly with a custom `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method in your class?

Comment: Does the order matter, so  are "1,2,3" and "3,2,1" equal? Does the count matter, so are "1,1,2" and "1,2" equal?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If he sums up everything I would say that the order does not matter

Comment: @ThreeFx: He does not sum up the lists, he sums up the  `Costs` property, the lists which are used to determine if two objects are equal is `List<int> NodeIDs`.

Comment: "1,2,3" and "3,2,1" are not equal and are not possible in the data set. Duplicates within the list are not possible "1, 1, ...". The lists have specific Start and End nodes, so it's mostly what's between those 2 that's different.

Answer (score 3):

```
.GroupBy(x=> string.Join(",", x.NodeIDs)).Select(x=>x.First())
```

That should be faster for big data than Distinct.

Comment: This will not work if you don't want order to matter. However it's a great trick and you don't need to use a new equalitycomparer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove duplicate objects according to equal lists you could create a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` for lists and use that for `Enumerable.GroupBy`. Then you just need to create new instances of your class for each group and sum up `Cost`.

Here is a possible implementation ([from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307928/how-to-group-a-list-of-lists-using-linq-ex-listlistint)):

```
public class ListEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<T> lhs, List<T> rhs)
    {
        return lhs.SequenceEqual(rhs);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> list)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 23;
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                hash = (hash * 31) + (item == null ? 0 : item.GetHashCode());
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a query that selects one (unique) instance per group:

```
var nodes = new List<TheClass>(); // fill ....
var uniqueAndSummedNodes = nodes
    .GroupBy(n => n.NodeIDs, new ListEqualityComparer<int>())
    .Select(grp => new TheClass
    {
        NodeID = grp.First().NodeID,  // just use the first, change accordingly
        Cost = grp.Sum(n => n.Cost),
        NodeIDs = grp.Key
    });
nodes = uniqueAndSummedNodes.ToList();
```

This implementation uses `SequenceEqual` which takes  the order and the number of occurences of each number in the list into account.

**Edit**: I've only just seen that you don't want to sum up the group's `Costs` but to sum up all groups' `Cost`, that's simple:

```
double totalCost = nodes.Sum(n => n.Cost);
```

If you dont want to sum up the group itself replace

```
...
Cost = grp.Sum(n => n.Cost),
```

with

```
...
Cost = grp.First().Cost, // presumes that all are the same
```